# Accessing Jasper Reports Server from Oracle Autonomous Database via REST API in APEX

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

I have configured Oracle APEX instance in autonomous database free tier instance. I have also configured a jasper reports server instance in OCI free tier. I can access database from jasper server but unable to call rest API from apex server. as per documentation UTL_HTTP.REQUEST can not be called on IP address of the server, can any one guide me how can I access jasper server from autonomous database server?

I have also tried to access the server via Internal FQDN, but not succeeded. please help